# Receiving "501 Not Implemented" when using HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, network-programming, httpurlconnection

My project is targeted to SDK 23, and from now on, as far as I know, I have to use `HttpURLConnection` instead of `HttpClient` to make post requests, but I keep getting `501` response code from my webservice (I'm pretty sure it's fully functional, I have no doubt) when making post requests to store users in a remote mysql database. Here follows the main connection code:

```
class DatabaseConnector extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private final String CONNECTION_URL = "webservice_address";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String response = "initial value";

        try {
            URL url = new URL(CONNECTION_URL);

            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setUseCaches(false);
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            con.setReadTimeout(10000);
            con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            json.put("query", params[0]);

            JSONObject conn = new JSONObject();
            conn.put("database", "database");
            conn.put("hostname", "hostname");
            conn.put("password", "password");
            conn.put("username", "username");
            conn.put("port", "port");

            json.put("conn", conn.toString());

            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(json.toString());
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            con.connect();

            //display what returns the POST request

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int HttpResult = con.getResponseCode();

            System.out.println("Response CODE: "+ con.getResponseCode());

            if (HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                System.out.println("Passed1");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));

                while ((response = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(response + "\n");
                }

                br.close();

                System.out.println("E: " + sb.toString());

                response = sb.toString();
            } else {
                System.out.println("E2: "+con.getResponseMessage());
                response = "Error1: "+con.getResponseMessage();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response = "Error2: "+e.toString();
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

And in my fragment I make the network calls:

```
try {
    String result = new DatabaseConnector().execute("SELECssT 1").get();
    Toast.makeText(ContentActivity.this, "Result: "+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Toast.makeText(ContentActivity.this, "Error3: "+ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Nevermind that wrong sql statement, it's meant to be like that, I want the webservice to echo back that syntax error. I have tried many stuff, codes, examples, but it doesn't seem to work.

**The point is: I keep getting error code *501 Not Implemented*. Why? And how can I fix that?**

**EDIT:**

Any tips or comments on how to improve the way I make network calls on android is welcome, I'm pretty new to that. I'm using a Async call but somehow it's still executing in the main thread, cause the debugger complains:

```
09-25 19:17:32.714  28853-28853/br.com.developer.package I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 80 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Thank you all.

Comment: "I have to use HttpURLConnection instead of HttpClient to make post requests" -- there are other alternatives, like OkHttp, or Apache's independent packaging of HttpClient for Android. "Why?" -- ask whoever is maintaining your server. They should have more information, such as error logs, that would indicate what particular problem they encountered in processing your request.

Comment: Hm, I heard of issues with Apache's HttpClient in android versions prior to 4, that's why I switched to HttpUrlConnection. And even if I change the sdk target from 23 to 22, to use HttpClient, android studio will shove a lot of errors on my face. -.-'

Comment: The problem with "Apache's HttpClient in android prior to 4" is for the built-in HttpClient. Those concerns do not apply for Apache's JAR. Personally, I would use OkHttp and not think twice, as `HttpUrlConnection`'s API leaves much to be desired. For example, OkHttp has built-in asynchronous options, so you do not have to fuss with your own `AsyncTask`.

Comment: @CommonsWare , I'm soo amazed to see such a clean, simple and functional API like OkHttp's. I'm now using it in my project and it's way better. Found this awesome example: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-OkHttp/article.html . If you CommonsWare post an answer mentioning the benefits of using OkHttp, I'd be glad to accept that as the correct answer.

Comment: An answer talking about OkHttp would not really answer your question of why you are getting 501's with the code that you have there, so that wouldn't be appropriate. That being said, I'm glad that OkHttp is working out for you. Square has a number of open source libraries, and pretty much all of them have very clean APIs, which is why those libraries tend to be popular.

Comment: Hm, I understand your point about what is a correct answer and I agree. I  appreciate your honesty and willingness to help. Thanks for the tip buddy.

Comment: This debate about the client code is pointless. It doesn't make any difference. The code here is working perfectly. It sent a request and delivers the response. The question here is why did the **server** deliver that response, and the answer is to be found at the server. Or else you sent the wrong request. You can do hat with any client.